# Adding Elements with Ids to a Div so I can access the new Elements with getElementById

Tags: javascript, dropdown, w3.css

*[Edit: Thanks to Ganesh's answer, it led me on the right track to what the actual problem was. So thanks for that. The problem was in my `for` loop I have `let i = 0, str = ""`, which meant I was creating a new `str` for the loop, which was different than the `str` outside the loop. This meant when I set `el.innerHTML = str` outside the loop, it was not the `str` that had been created in the loop.]*

I am creating a `w3.css` dropdown with canvases and labels in it. I am basing it on the example with the title 'Clickable Dropdowns' on the webpage [W3.CSS Dropdowns](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_dropdowns.asp).

```
<div class="w3-dropdown-click">
    <button onclick="OnClickDoStuff()" class="w3-button w3-black">
        <canvas id="imageMain"></canvas>
        &nbsp;
        <label id="labelMain">Name</label>
    </button>
    <div id="divInnards" class="w3-dropdown-content w3-bar-block w3-border">
        <!-- Stuff inserted with javascript -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I am adding the elements of `divInnards` in javascript.

```
let el = document.getElementById("divInnards");
let str, iStr;

for(let i=0, str = "";i < 24; i++){
    iStr = i.toString();
    str += "<a href=\"#\" class=\"w3-bar-item w3-button\""
                    + " id=\"divLink" + iStr + "\""
                    + " onclick=\"OnClickLink(" + iStr + ")\""
            + ">"
            + "<canvas id=\"divCanvas" + iStr + "\" ></canvas>"
            + "&nbsp;"
            + "<label id=\"divLabel" + iStr + "\">Name</label>"
        + "</a>";
}
el.innerHTML = str;
```

However, then when I try and get `divCanvas0` later on, I get null.

```
let cnv = document.getElementById("divCanvas0"); // cnv === null :(
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the canvas actually exists on the page when you are executing the getElementById? Inspect the page and check. That is the likely issue.

Comment: @Deadron, I am using Visual Studio Code, how do I do that? I can inspect `document`, but where would it be under in the `document` tree?

Comment: Use your browser's page inspector in the developer menu.

Comment: No, the content I am adding with javascript to `divInnards` does not appear to have been added to the document.

Comment: Well you can't retrieve something that doesn't exist so your problem is in the code inserting the content.

Comment: Anyone have any idea what I have done is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

because after laste itration istr becomes 23, try this

```
let el = document.getElementById("divInnards");
let str, iStr;

for(let i=0;i < 24; i++){
    iStr = i.toString();
    str +=  "<a href=\"#\" class=\"w3-bar-item w3-button\""
                    + " id=\"divLink" + iStr + "\""
                    + " onclick=\"OnClickLink(" + iStr + ")\""
            + ">"
            + "<canvas id=\"divCanvas" + iStr + "\" ></canvas>"
            + "&nbsp;"
            + "<label id=\"divLabel" + iStr + "\">Name</label>"
        + "</a>";
        
        el.innerHTML = str;
  



}
```

Comment: in the first iteration I get `innerHTML` with `undefined<a href...`. However, I now can access `divCanvas0` without it giving `null`. However, I do not understand why your code is working. Should it be `str = "<a href...` and `el.innerHTML += ...`. Because the latter works as well. But I do not understand why?